# Receiving Data from MacBAT 5 in python

Tags: networking, communication, protocols, data-transfer, python

I need to be able to communicate with a PLUM-EVC, [MacBat 5](http://plummac.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/MacBAT-5_karta-katalogowa_2018_EN_v5.pdf) from a remote server using Python. I have been given parameters, IP and Port which are required to get the data from EVC.

I am completely new to this field. Can anyone please give some context or an example on how to approach this programatically to be able to send command and get EVC data.

Sample commands and response are in the below link.

[Standard Transmission Protocols](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yojZp6d7fH6OKjTT4Osu7azYllLLJML2)

Data parameters from MacBAT 5 are given in below link.

[MacBAT 5 User Data Structure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tTBt6mXM_9a65T6bswAQsIkSU8nI6keY)

Edit: I am trying to get data from MacBAT 5. More details about the data structure are given in the above link. And the communication can be done through the protocols MODBUS TCP/IP, MODBUS RTU, GAZMODEM as given in the manual of MacBAT 5.

So, I need to write a python code using one of the above protocols(I only have IP and port) to connect and get data from MacBAT 5.

Comment: Hi Neal, welcome to the site. You might get better answers if you ask for a more precise use case. What do you want to do, what data do you want to extract for example. Moreover it would be helpful to learn more about your setup to be able to answer your question. Just asking for an example seldom leads to very helpful answers.

Comment: Any such additions can be made to the question via [edit].

Comment: Alas, both of your links are blocked by my comapny's firewall. Are these just standard HTTP RESTful APIS? I.e GET/POST  such as `https://someURL.com/write_data.php?value=42` or `https://someURL.com/read_data.php` or is there more to it?

Comment: The given links are of google drive.

Comment: Giving the above links here for your reference. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yojZp6d7fH6OKjTT4Osu7azYllLLJML2/view

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tTBt6mXM_9a65T6bswAQsIkSU8nI6keY/view

Comment: So what research have you done around python Modbus libraries?